# Loading UTF8 CSV files generated on a Mac into Excel on Windows: does not recognize encoding

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell, notepad++, csv, utf-8

When I generate a UTF8 CSV file in Excel (or some other way) on Windows and then open it n Excel, I expect it to ask me to choose the right encoding.

I got a UTF8 CSV file that was generated on a Mac. No matter how I open it in Excel on Windows 10, it automatically opens it as ASCII garbling the non-ASCII text in the process. The only way to ingest it by using the import function but it takes more steps to do it than a straight open.

When I open the file in Notepad++ it shows the foreign language text correctly, so this program is smart enough to guess that it's UTF8. Is there a way to convert the file into some form that Excel does recognize to ask for the encoding on open? I highly prefer a command I can run from CMD or POWERSHELL since I might get a bunch of new CSVs that I would like to convert as a batch rather than manually.

Comment: Try fiddling with the encoding in the Encoding menu button in Notepad++ and saving a new copy. I've been able to work around similar problems by saving this way in the past. I'm not aware of a CLI tool to do this but I'm sure they exist.

Comment: Open the file in a hex editor and figure out WTF happened.  LOOK at what is used for line endings.. LOOK at the [UTF header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and see if it is what is expected.

Comment: It worked when I converted the original in N++ using Encoding->Convert to UTF-8-BOM, but not as Encoding->Convert to UTF-8. Still, a less than perfect solution since I need to convert a batch. Not sure if there is a command-line command that's an equivalent to this conversion

Comment: Is it possible to generate the CSV from the Mac in UTF8-BOM ? Excel will only recognize UTF8 files if there is a Byte Order Mark present or by using manual data import..

Comment: You can use PowerShell to convert to UTF8-BOM like this: `(Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\blah.csv' -Encoding UTF8) | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\blah.csv' -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: Excel works better with CSV files if you **Import** rather than **Open**.  You can use either `Power Query` or the legacy text import wizard.  In either case, you will have the opportunity to specify the encoding.